# Using jQuery to update multiple background CSS definitions

Tags: jquery, css

Can anyone think of a way to update more than one background definition at a time?

I've gotten this far with some code but I want to update a lot of different flavors of gradient background for one element.

```
$('ul#tabs li').on('mousemove',function(e){ 
var x= Math.round(((e.pageX - this.offsetLeft)*100)/$(this).width());
x= x-10;
$(this).find(".highLight").css({
    'background': '-webkit-linear-gradient(left, 
        rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,
        rgba(255,255,255,0.5)'+x+'%,
        rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%)'
});});
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use http://lea.verou.me/prefixfree/

> A script that lets you use only unprefixed CSS properties everywhere.
>   It works behind the scenes, adding the current browser’s prefix to any
>   CSS code, only when it’s needed.
>
> ..
>
> Lets jQuery’s .css() method to get and set unprefixed properties (requires plugin)

Alternatively, you can call `.css()` for each browser's gradient syntax:

```
var $highLight = $(this).find(".highLight");
$highLight.css('background', '-webkit-linear-gradient( .. )');
$highLight.css('background', '-moz-linear-gradient( .. )');
//include others such as opera, old webkit, microsoft
$highLight.css('background', 'linear-gradient( .. )');
```

Only the gradient syntax that each browser supports will be applied.

Comment: The alternative worked. (Couldn't make prefixtree do much of anything, odd.) Functions in all my test browsers now. Fantastic, thank you! It's odd, I just assumed that any new definition of background would overwrite the previous version. In fact, it's kind of crazy that it doesn't.